# Get the elements in a vector that are not repeated a specified number of times

Tags: r

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
v <- c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
```

How can I get the elements that are not repeated twice? In other words, they are only present once or more than twice in the vector.

Thank you!

Comment: You want to select or just know which one ? I would say `table(v)!=2` is what you need

Comment: I want to know which ones! That works, thanks!

Comment: Ok then `names(which(table(v)!=2))` gives you the answer directly !

Comment: The full answer would be: `v[v %in% names(which(table(v) != 2))]`

Comment: Is your vector always in sorted order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `subset` with `ave`

```
> subset(v, ave(v, v, FUN = length) != 2)
[1] 1 3 3 3
```

Comment: Thomas,  something odd happens with bigger inputs.  Try:   `v <- c(1,2,2,7,7,7, 8,8, 3,3,3,4,4); v <- rep(v,times = 10)`   Your `subset` formula returns the entire vector.  I haven't had time to trace it down, but suspect it's because the same values (and thus same "factors") show up repeatedly.

Comment: I think that depends on if OP wants to process it in terms of the run length or not.

Answer (score 1):

Edited on carls suggestion to go further than my first answer had, and bugfix

```
rv <- rle(sort(v))
vals <- rv$values[which(rv$lengths!=2)]
v[v %in% vals]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this alternate approach

```r
library(dplyr)

v <- data.frame(v=v) %>% mutate(n=n(), .by=v) %>% filter(n!=2) %>% select(v)
v$v

[1] 1 3 3 3
```

Comment: this, however, requires a few additional libraries to be loaded.  At the least, please edit to identify said libs